# CSS background image are not showing up

Tags: css

Why the css background image not showing up? I checked the image location are correct.

The HTML Code:

```html
<section id="hero-image">
  <h1>paper</h1>
</section>
```

The CSS Code:

```css
.hero-image{
    background-image: url(img/Slideshow/slide.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS code, try changing the `.hero-image` to `#hero-image`. This is because you have defined "hero-image" as an ID. And you use `#hero-image` when searching for an ID within your HTML.